# How should I keep my http connection alive with java servlet?

Tags: java, http, servlets, connection

In my java servlet I am throwing an exception at certain point and I want to keep my connection alive as I am expecting specific response from user to that exception and I want to process that response further.
How should I achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked at a WS for this? They are by default a persistent connection.. Otherwise you are using up an http request.. not really meant to be kept open all the time.

Comment: I am communicating with git client and expecting response from it. That's why added it in tags.

Comment: @VaidehiDharkar: and yet you thought that this information was irrelevant in your question, so you didn't mention it in your question. If it was irrelevant, it's irrelevant. If it was relevant, it needs to be *mentioned*.

Comment: You don't need to do this. The connection will probably be kept-alive anyway, but it doesn't matter. The following request will come in the same *session*, and that's all you need.

Comment: I am trying to process request from git client using java servlets.
In first call from git client when we get blank authentication, I am throwing an exception. However, in response to that exception, git client was able to pass authentication details when I was using dropwizard framework, but in case of servlets, connections breaks when I throw exception.
I am trying to know how should I manage to connect to git client from servlets?

Comment: You would need to return a 403 status code rather than throwing an exception for that to work. But either way the next communication from the client with the authentication is a new request and doesn't need to be on the same connection.